# HELM: How to convert a string into lower/upper case inside if-else condition?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Use case: I have values.yaml where I have a field `mode`.

Values.yaml

```
mode: start
```

or user can enter a value for the field `mode` in any of the below mentioned ways:

```
mode: STart or START or sTart
```

Now, I have a file where I am using an if condition as shown below:

```
command: {{ if eq .Values.mode "start" }} do this {{ esle }} do that {{ end }}
```

Now, my challenge is how can I covert the ".Values.mode" into lower alphabets before doing the comparison. I have tried the below mentioned ways:

1.

```
{{ if eq .Values.mode | lower "start" }} do this {{ esle }} do that {{ end }}
```

2. 

```
{{ if eq lower .Values.mode "start" }} do this {{ esle }} do that {{ end }}
```

Both of the above methods errored out.

Note: we are using a third-party tool, hence JSON schema check won't help me.

Answer (score 15):

[`lower`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lower) is a function handed to you in the templates. It has a return value, which you wish to compare to another value.

Simply group the function call of `lower` with parenthesis:

```
{{ if eq "start" (lower .Values.mode) }} do this {{ else }} do that {{ end }}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,,  I am using helm 3 and it didn't work there.. Its going into else part. :(

Comment: @SHC Then it looks your mode is not what you think it is. Try printing its value, look for leading and trailing whitespaces...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I printed the value and there is no spaces. When i assign a value to a key with lower fucntion it works ex (mode = {{ .Values.mode | lower }}. but within in if condition part its not taking effect.